# Hyperlink to .bat file within an Excel file, no longer works. "No Program is registered to open this file"

Tags: microsoft-excel, batch, hyperlink, links

I have a hyperlink in Excel that is directed to a batch file on my domain network (actually multiple links for multiple files). For years, I can click the hyperlinks in Excel and after clicking 'OK' regarding security concern, the linked batch file on my network would be executed. It worked great. Now within the past ~60 days perhaps, myself and colleagues can no longer get this to work. A message appears in Excel that just says "No program is registered to open this file." I can run the batch files themselves from my computer just fine. I have tried to play with security in settings and have been searching google for the last ~60 days and have found no solutions!

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed any software before this issue?

I suggest you locate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bat`, check whether there is any other program associated with .bat file.

1. If yes, you may backup the registry of .bat first, and restore .bat files with default settings.

Generally, the default registry entries are `OpenWithList` and `OpenWithProgids`, for more you may refer to following images.

[image]

[image]

2. If not, I suggest you add the path of these bacth files into Excel Trusted Location. (File > Options > Trusted Center > Trusted Center Settings > Trusted Locations > Add new location).

Run SFC scan.

- Search "Command Prompt", right-click it, run as Administrator.
- Click Continue or supply Administrator credentials if prompted.
- In the Command Prompt window type the following, and press Enter:
  [sfc /scannow](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e)

Comment: my .bat registry looks like yours and i ran the sfc scan. it says no issues found. I can't figure out how to point excel to registry keys as trusted locations. it doesn't except the registry key address as valid when i copy and paste the "computer/hkey_current..."  

But at any rate, Excel isn't saying the file isn't trusted. it just says no program is registered to open the file; and again, batch files run just fine when i click on them directly.